# A single column of letters appears under a CSS float shape

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to make a "header" space where text in a div flows around a rectangle, and have several of them scattered throughout the div, except I want to define all the headers/footers at the beginning of the element for reasons. Everything mostly works fine, except that when I begin typing right after the float, the letters form a single line until I either push "space" or type more letters than the height of the column. I cannot for the life of my figure out why it's doing that.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/badcoderboy/fchwv3ag/8/) is an fiddle that shows it in chrome. You can also try it for yourself.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the CSS for the floating div that the letters go under

```
.ql-header-div { 
    /*top, right, bottom and left*/
    shape-outside: polygon(0 0,100% 0, 100% 72px, 0 72px);
    shape-margin: 10px;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0,100% 0, 100% 72px, 0 72px);
    width: 100%;
    height: 792px;
    float: right;
    opacity: .5;
    background-color:#F6C1C1;
    color:#000;
}
```

Comment: I cant tell what you want to do, do you have a sketch of the effect you want?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/QVviYmV.png

    <div id="div1">
 <div class="header" id="header1"></div>
 <div class="header" id="header2"></div>
 <p>text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  
  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  
  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text 
  [...]
 </p>
</div>